# Unable to connect to AWS ALB through client VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I am creating a `staging` env using `AWS` and i want it to be accessible through `VPN` only.
The env was created using Fargate.
I have:

- 1 `front lb` connected to several front tasks.
- 1 `back lb` connected to several back tasks.

I created the VPN client endpoint.
I can connect to the VPN and ssh to instances in the same security group as my front and back lb. (I tried to start an ec2 instance with the same security group and it works).

But for some reason i am **unable** to **connect** to the **albs** using their **dns name** or the name used in the **route 53** record.

Did i miss something that should be configured for dns to work on aws ressources through the VPN?

I hope this was detailed enough, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you created a public, Internet-facing ALB. For the ALB to work internally in the VPC (and only in the VPC), you need to create an internal ALB.

See the "Scheme" setting in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html).

Comment: Exactly Mark! I also found the issue yesterday! Thanks for the answer!